# Unhandled promise rejection: undefined is not a function on Firebase reference

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-storage

I am getting unhandled promise rejection maybe because of `ref` is not passing please review this if possible. I'll be thankful to you.

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...ref.on...')]

In upload file code is distributed based on their functionality:

```
import firebase from '../../firebase'

const getLocalPath = async (uri)=>{
  const response = await fetch(uri);
  const blob = await response.blob();
  return blob
}

const upload = async (blob, className,acc)=>{
  const ref = await firebase.storage().ref(`/${className}`).child(`/${acc}`).put(blob)
  console.log('trigger')
  console.log('ref', ref)
  return ref
};

const getLink = async (ref, className, acc)=>{
  await ref.on(
    "state_changed",
    (snapshot) => {},
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    },
    () => {
      storage
        .ref(`/${className}`)
        .child(`/${acc}`)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then(async (url) => {
            // setURL(url)
            console.log(url)
            return url
        });
    }
  );
}
export {getLink, getLocalPath}
export default upload
```

This is where I use it:

```
const Publish= async ()=>{
  setLoading(true)
  console.log(id)
  var count = 1

  const blob = await getLocalPath(images[0])
  const ref = await upload(blob, `serviceImages/${id}`, `${count}`, setURL)
  const uri = await getLink(ref, `serviceImages/${id}`, `${count}` )
  console.log(uri)

  setLoading(false)
}
```

Comment: What is `ref` and does it have a function named `on`? Set a breakpoint and check.

Answer (score 0):

[`firebase.storage.Reference#put`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#put) returns a [`firebase.storage.UploadTask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask). This `UploadTask` class does have a [`UploadTask#on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#on) method, BUT, because you used `await`, you actually get a [`UploadTaskSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) object instead which is the result of [`UploadTask#then()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#then).

So to return the `UploadTask` instead of the `UploadTaskSnapshot`, omit the `await` here.

```
const upload = (blob, className, acc) => {
  return firebase.storage()
    .ref(`/${className}`)
    .child(`/${acc}`)
    .put(blob)
};
```

But if you want to wait for the upload, just `await` the `UploadTask` when you consume the code.

```
const blob = await getLocalPath(images[0])
const uploadTask = upload(blob, `serviceImages/${id}`, `${count}`, setURL); // note no await here
const snapshot = await uploadTask; // wait for upload to finish
const uri = await getLink(uploadTask, `serviceImages/${id}`, `${count}`)
```

You could also do this:

```
const blob = await getLocalPath(images[0])
const uploadTask = upload(blob, `serviceImages/${id}`, `${count}`, setURL);
const [snapshot, uri] = await Promise.all([
  uploadTask,
  getLink(uploadTask, `serviceImages/${id}`, `${count}`)
]);
```

You can also simplify `getLink` to just:

```
const getLink = async (uploadTask) => {
  return uploadTask
    .then((snapshot) => snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
}
```

which leads to:

```
const blob = await getLocalPath(images[0])
const uploadTask = upload(blob, `serviceImages/${id}`, `${count}`, setURL);
const [snapshot, uri] = await Promise.all([
  uploadTask,
  getLink(uploadTask)
]);
```

---

As a side note, try to avoid using `await` if you are just going to return the value on the next line. It just adds an unnecessary step as you can see here:

```
const getLocalPath = async (uri)=>{
  const response = await fetch(uri);
  const blob = await response.blob();
  return blob
}
```

effectively becomes

```
const getLocalPath = async (uri) => {
  return fetch(uri)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => blob); // <- this line does nothing interesting
}
```

So just write it as this instead:

```
const getLocalPath = async (uri) => {
  const response = await fetch(uri);
  return response.blob();
}
```